# python: __init__ template

Tags: python, initialization, python-3.x

I noticed I often write the following:

```
class X:
  def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
    self.var1 = var1
    self.var2 = var2
    self.var3 = var3
    # more code here
```

Is it a good idea to make a template that I can reuse instead of doing this every time? If so, how should I do that?

Comment: What do you need a template for? Is it really that burdensome to type it out?

Comment: Not burdensome, but I hate repetitive code. More chance of a typo, distracts from seeing the important stuff, etc.

Comment: I agree that it's annoyingly repetitive, but I'd advise against this: using a magic helper to do this for you will make the code much less understandable by other people; the above can be understood instantly.  It also means you have to rewrite code if you later add a parameter that's *not* stored in the object.

Comment: Why don't you make a template in your IDE and have it expand `class` to the long declaration?

Comment: Although it might seem tiresome, the savings in keystrokes is not worth the loss in maintainability. In general, the pythonic way of doing things says be up front about how things work. In addition, the çost of the machinery required to burry those details can bite you if you're creating a lot of objects. It might seem like a burden now, but you'll be happy you didn't make your __init__ overly generic when you come back in year or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest using such templates in production code, because

```
Explicit is better than implicit.
```

For throw-away prototypes it might be acceptable. Here is an example from the python recipes:

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577382-keyword-argument-injection-with-python-decorators/

It defines a decorator with can be attached to `__init__`:

```
def injectArguments(inFunction):
    """
    This function allows to reduce code for initialization 
    of parameters of a method through the @-notation
    You need to call this function before the method in this way: 
    @injectArguments
    """
    def outFunction(*args, **kwargs):
        _self = args[0]
        _self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
        # Get all of argument's names of the inFunction
        _total_names = \
            inFunction.func_code.co_varnames[1:inFunction.func_code.co_argcount]
        # Get all of the values
        _values = args[1:]
        # Get only the names that don't belong to kwargs
        _names = [n for n in _total_names if not kwargs.has_key(n)]

        # Match names with values and update __dict__
        d={}
        for n, v in zip(_names,_values):
            d[n] = v
        _self.__dict__.update(d)
        inFunction(*args,**kwargs)

    return outFunction
```

A test:

```
class Test:
    @injectArguments
    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    t = Test('mickey', surname='mouse')
    print t.name, t.surname
```

Comment: This makes me vaguely nervous; it feels like far too much magic for too small a gain.

Comment: (_I _can _also _only _wonder _why _it's _written _like _this...)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a wrapper which analyses the names and creates attributes for `self`. But is that really needed? I mean, there will be loads more code than this. If you have too many constructor parameters, then maybe refactoring to something more sane is a better option?

Otherwise - if you expect someone else to work on your project, then either name the decorator `@magic_you_should_really_read_about`, or just write the standard code ;) From "import this": `Explicit is better than implicit.`